# Runnable Interface and Lambda, is this one of the right ways?

Tags: java, lambda

```
class RunnerL implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("demo3-Hello: " + i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

Then, in main function:

        Thread t1 = new Thread ( () -> new RunnerL ().run() );
        Thread t2 = new Thread ( () -> new RunnerL ().run() );

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
```

This code works.  But is this the one of the right ways to do it?

Also, why does following does not work??

```
Runnable task3 = () -> new RunnerL ();
new Thread (task3).start();
```

If I change it to `Runnable task3 = () -> new RunnerL ().run()` OR `Runnable task3 = new RunnerL()`, it works, why?

Answer (score 1):

Because the following code only creates the `RunnerL` instance but the `run()` method of `Runnable` doesn't really run it (doesn't execute the run method). The thread calls `run()` on the `Runnable` instance (therefore only calls the lambda):

```
 Runnable task3 = () -> new RunnerL ();
```

While the following creates the `RunnerL` instance, and when the Thread is launched, it calls `run()` method directly on that instance:

```
 Runnable task = new RunnerL();
```

The above is actually the best option, the other one which works unnecessarily wraps `Runnable` into another `Runnable`.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda expressions provide the implementation (definition) of the method inside the functional interface (contains single abstract method only). So here, you need to understand that you are actually providing the implementation for the abstract `run()` method of the `Runnable` interface.

To get this concept better, **just add the constructor to your `RunnerL` class** as shown below so that you can notice what is really happening:

```
class RunnerL implements Runnable {

    public RunnerL() {
        System.out.println(" constructor called ");
    }

    //Add your run() method here
}
```

> Why does following does not work? 
>   Runnable task3 = () -> new RunnerL(); 
>   new Thread (task3).start();

This Lambda expression (i.e., implementation for the `Runnable` interface's `run()` method) simply creates the object for `RunnerL` & calls the above constructor (i.e., prints the statement 'constructor called').

> If I change it to Runnable task3 = () -> new RunnerL ().run(), it works, why?

This Lambda expression creates the object, calls the constructor by printing 'constructor called' & then calls your `run()` method as well.

Answer (score 0):

**To use the Runnable interface to create and start a thread, you have to do the following:**

1) Create a class that implements Runnable.

```
class RunnerL implements Runnable {}
```

2)Provide a run method in the Runnable class.

```
 public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
```

3) Create an instance of the Thread class and pass your Runnable object to its constructor as a parameter.

**A Thread object is created that can run your Runnable class.**

```
RunnableClass rc = new RunnableClass();
Thread t = new Thread(rc);
```

4)Call the Thread object’s start method.

**The run method of your Runnable object is called and executes in a separate thread.**

```
 t.start();
```

Runnable task3 = () -> new RunnerL ();

```
**This is not running your runnable class.Just creating an instance.**
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java8 you don't actually need to implement `Runnable` in your class. Java will accept the method as a `Runnable` if it has the right signature. So, for example:

```
class CountToTen {
    public void count() {
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

CountToTen counter = new CountToTen();
Thread thread1 = new Thread (counter::count);
thread1.start();
```

This is the point of functional interfaces in Java 8: you mostly do not need to explicitly implement them because lambda expressions (including method references) that match the interface's sole non-default method's signature can act as an implementation of the interface.